# Arcane trickster and proficiency bonus

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, proficiency

A quick question regarding the rogue's arcane trickster archetype. In his spell table (PHB p.98), there is no column with the proficiency bonus, like for the other spellcaster classes.

Does this mean that the arcane trickster doesn't add his proficiency bonus to his spell attack rolls ?

Because PHB p.205 says

> **Attack rolls**
>
> [...] Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

So I guess the column is just missing in the table p.98 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule says you add your proficiency bonus to spell attack rolls, so you do.

It's not missing from the table, it's just in another table on page 95, along with all the other core Rogue numbers. Spellcasters usually have spells as a core feature and they have all their level-based numbers in one table (see the Sorcerer just a few pages further on, on page 100). The Arcane Trickster though is a set of added abilities on top of Rogue. Rogues don't normally get spells, so the stuff that's normally in one table for a spellcaster — including proficiency bonus and spells known/slots — is for an Arcane Trickster split across the Rogue table and the Arcane Trickster table.

Looking at it another way: it wouldn't make sense to repeat Proficiency Bonus in both tables (it would be a waste of expensive page space), and it wouldn't make sense to combine the tables (all the spell stuff would be confusing for non–Arcane Trickster Rogue players), so it makes the most sense to have these things separate. Proficiency Bonus is the same for every Rogue of a given level,<sup>1</sup> so it goes in the main Rogue table; spell details are not the same for every Rogue, so they go in a separate table. Being in separate tables doesn't imply that Proficiency doesn't apply to the spells.

1. <sup>Actually, Proficiency Bonus is the same for everyone of a given level regardless of class, but having a separate "everyone's Proficiency Bonus table" would just scatter the information around the book and make it that much harder to use. In this case, it's worth spending expensive page space repeating it, so that everything a class needs is in one place.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There is no proficiency bonus listed in that chart because it is listed with the main rogue chart. The same is true of the eldritch knight archtype of the fighter class.

As an aside proficiency bonuses dont really need to be listed with eaxh class because it is completely dependent on character level not class level. I.e. a fighter5/rogue5 has the same proficiency bonus as a cleric10.

Answer (score 0):

The Arcane Trickster is an Archetype. When you level up, you still take levels as a Rogue, and the Arcane Trickster features scale up as you gain levels in the Rogue class. It is not its own class, so it doesn't need to have the same stuff a class has. So when you need to reference your Proficiency Bonus as an Arcane Trickster or an Eldritch Knight, you reference the table of the class the Archetype actually belongs to.